# Cannot get react-i18next to read JSON files via FETCH backend

Tags: reactjs, i18next, create-react-app, react-i18next

I'm trying to use `react-i18next` on the client using the `i18next-fetch-backend`, and even though I can get to the JSON translation files via a browser, something is screwy with how they're being handled during the `init` routine.

For the record, I'm using `create-react-app` as the basis of my front-end React application, if that makes a difference, and so far all of my testing is in localhost (with the React app on localhost:3000, and the "server" on localhost:8000).

Here's my init file:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';

import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import Cache from 'i18next-localstorage-cache';
import Fetch from 'i18next-fetch-backend';

i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(Cache)
  .use(Fetch)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en', 
    ns: ['common','app'],
    defaultNS: 'common',
    preload: ['en'], 
    wait: true,
    backend: {
      loadPath: 'http://localhost:8000/static/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
      addPath: 'http://localhost:8000/static/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}',
      parse: function (data) { console.log("DATA", data) },
      init: {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        credentials: 'include',
        cache: 'default'
      }
    },

    cache: {
      enabled: true,
      prefix: 'i18next_translations_',
      expirationTime: 24*60*60*1000 //one day
    },

    debug: true,

    detection: {
      order: ['localStorage', 'cookie'], 
      lookupCookie: 'i18nextLng',
      lookupLocalStorage: 'i18nextLng',
      caches: ["localStorage"] 
      //cookieMinutes: 10 // if we want the cookie to expire
    },

  });

export default i18n;
```

...and then the Component that wraps my app looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next'
import i18n from './i18n' // the init code from above

export default class Localize extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        {this.props.children}
      </I18nextProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

...and finally, the Component where the translation should happen:

```
class TestTranslate extends Component {

  render () {
    const { t } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
          {t('key1')}
          {t('key3')}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default translate()(LearnHome)
```

If I look at the Chrome debugger when I load the page, I see the following:
[image: Chrome console]

Two FETCH commands are executed: one for `common.json` and one for `app.json`. To my eye, it sure looks like both FETCH commands execute properly, but then no data at all is making it to the `parse()` function in the `backend` init config data.

And in fact, if I pop over to the Chrome network tab, the browser sure seems to think that the data was properly returned to the browser from the server:

[image: Chrome network tab]

So I'm baffled as to what's going on. I've pored through the i18next docs and several examples, but have so far come up empty. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The question itself is the best resource I've found for setting up react-i18next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out. It's got nothing to do with i18next. We are running a Django built-in dev web server inside a Vagrant instance for local development. By default, Django's web server doesn't put headers on static files as they are returned to the client. My local client environment (`localhost:3000`) was in essence making a CORS request to my local Django environment (`localhost:8000`), so we had to reconfigure our dev Django server to return CORS headers on static file requests.