# How to fix 'no fallback UI was specified' in react i18next using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-i18next, react-suspense

I am trying to implement i18next in my react component using the useTranslation hook, but it keeps saying:

> Uncaught Error: Test suspended while rendering, but no fallback UI was specified.
>
> Add a `<Suspense fallback=...>` component higher in the tree to provide a loading indicator or placeholder to display.

How can I add the `<Suspense>` any higher than what I've got? What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this? It seems to work OK when I use the `<Translation>` component. Naturally, it also seems to work OK if I turn Suspense off and try to handle it myself, but that sort of defeats the purpose, I think. How can I make this actually work? Do I have the Fetch backend misconfigured?

## Test.js

```
import React, { Suspense, useState, useEffect, lazy } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import i18n from './i18n';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

export default function Test( props ){
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation( 'bingo_game' );

    return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <div>
        Pant leg
      </div>
    </Suspense>
    )
}

Test.propTypes = {
  token: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

and

## i18n.js

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import LngDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

import Fetch from "i18next-fetch-backend";

  i18n
    .use(LngDetector) //language detector
    .use(Fetch)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
      backend: {
        loadPath: "/infra/locales/{{ns}}.json",
        // path to post missing resources
        addPath: "locales/add/{{ns}}",
        // define how to stringify the data when adding missing resources
        stringify: JSON.stringify
      },
      defaultNS: "base",
      fallbackLng: "en",
      debug: true,
      initImmediate: false
    });

export default i18n;
```

I've gone over the docs that I could find as well as [this SO post that is not my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415899/cannot-get-react-i18next-to-read-json-files-via-fetch-backend).

Comment: which component are you using Lazy on?

Comment: The [docs](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook) don't show the use of `Lazy`, but adding this:
`const { t, i18n } = lazy(() => useTranslation( 'bingo_game' ));`
seems to fix it here but not in a more complex component - is this the way it should be done?

Answer (score 10):

in your `i18n` file add this, it will do the magic :)

```
.init({
   react: {
     useSuspense: false,
     ...

  });
```

Comment: This is rather similar to the earlier answer but I'm still not eager to disable Suspense. Ultimately, I've solved this by wrapping all my components in a sort of Suspense wrapper. I think what I probably want in the long run is to move over to one of the React Router options...

Comment: yeah its really does

Answer (score 4):

It's not best way but I can recommend you to turn off suspense by adding this lines to your's config

```
i18n
  .init({
  ...
  // react i18next special options (optional)
  react: {
    useSuspense: false,
    wait: false,
  },
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it worked, but I don’t want to disable the feature, I want it to work properly.

Comment: At some point you'll want to add tests to your project and suspense doesn't work properly with them

Comment: Can you please explain further (@travinkov)? I have a battery of tests on the rails side of my app and a few strategic `try`/`catch` (or the rails equivalent - I forget) and `sleep` statements seems to be handling everything so far. Is there something else I need to be concerned about?

Answer (score 1):

Using useSuspense: false is ok but you need to use ready state in this case as well, otherwise your translation keys appear at interface until i18next is ready... Similar to this:

```
const { t, i18n, ready } = useTranslation()
```

and in the render section:

```
{ready && (<SampleComponent />)}
```

Comment: This makes sense and I didn't realise that they made _ready_ available. I've actually re-architected the system such that this is no longer an issue, but I'll test this if I reintroduce the need later (which I might).

Answer (score 1):

You can set `useSuspense: false` in `useTranslation` options.

`const { t } = useTranslation("your-namespace", {useSuspense: false});`

https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#not-using-suspense

Comment: I like that this would operate on a per-case basis, thanks. It is helpful and different from the others below, but ultimately, this is more of a suspense architecture issue, I think. I ultimately re-architected my frontend to solve this and this is no longer an issue for me - another reason I cannot mark this as solved. Sorry.